# Conditionally format column A if cell row contains "z"

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, countif

I want to highlight cells in column A (using the conditional formatting tool) if the cell's corresponding row contains the letter `z` anywhere within that row.  I want to do this so I can sort data to the top if it is highlighted in column A.

I'm using the formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$AA1,"*z*")
```

But I don't want to highlight the entire row, just the corresponding cell in column A for that row.

What is the formula to do this?

Comment: Please look at the updated question.

Comment: Would you want to count `buzz` as a cell with `z` in it or only cells with ONLY `z`?

Comment: Any instance of z so =COUNTIF(($A1:$AA1,"*z*").

Comment: what that does is highlight all the cells for instance of z, but really I just want to highlight the cell in column A. I'm wondering how to write the formula.. is it =$A1=($A1:$AA1,"*z*")? I'm not sure..

Comment: I'm thinking you will need a new Conditional Formatting rule for each column because the `Applies to` option will need to be different.

Answer (score 1):

Select ColumnA then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$AA1,"*z*")>0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select highlighting OK, OK.

This will apply only to Column A (because of the selection).

Answer (score -1):

This seemed to work for me when testing with a 3x3 cell table:

1. Highlight A1:A3
2. Conditional Formatting>New Rule>Use a formula to determine which cells to format
3. Formula:

   =COUNTIF($B1:$C1,"*z*")

Then only cells in A were highlighted.

Comment: I thought you'd want the flexibility to highlight cells in column B  if they contained your string, Not just recolor one column

Answer (score -2):

> "I want to do this so I can sort data to the top if it is highlighted
>   in column A."

Ok, first of all, you don't need to use conditional formatting to sort. Second of all you wouldn't want to reference A1 in your formula `=COUNTIF($A1:$AA1,"z")` - it is a circular reference and any formula you put in column A would not return "z" anyways because you are using it for your COUNTIF formula.

The formula you want to use is:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B1:$AA1,"z")>0,1,0)
```

If you want to look for any row that contains a z anywhere in a string you would want to do a wildcard countif:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B1:$AA1,"*z")>0,1,0)
```

Then you can just sort on column A for all your data - high to low.

Basically you have demonstrated a basic misunderstanding of how to sort in excel(no offense). This should help you. Good Luck.

Comment: Yes, you can sort using conditional formatting. He wants to change a cell color using conditional formatting and sort on that color. Very possible. And if the formula used in the question is for a conditional formatting condition then it is not a circular reference. It's not the right answer but it's on the right track.

Comment: Yea, you CAN use conditional formatting as a sorting mechanism - but why would you want to? If he wanted to he could just conditional format column A if it contains a 1 in my example. But he would still just sort on the value of the cell. So, basically, one of us has an inherent misunderstanding of his question. I guess we will see who that is in a bit.

Comment: The conditional formatting let's you have items which are important to you be always visible too. So if you sort on Column B, Column A cells are still colored. It's just a nice visual cue and it doesn't add columns of data to a table. Sometimes people don't like extraneous "worker" columns. Especially if you then pass the sheet along to someone else, then you need to explain why there is this column with no real data in it. Putting the color on the data makes life a little simpler.

Comment: In my example if you sort on column B the cells in column A would still be visible and you could apply a conditional formatting to them if you want. But Ok, my misunderstanding. I assumed that the goal was to sort it - not to make it look pretty - because for me personally it would be about the sorting.

Comment: Yeah, and I don't know what odpogn's goals are but from my experience that is the reasoning I use for files which move between multiple people.

Comment: I usually prefer worker columns. I just try to make the result something descriptive like if(test,"row contains z", "row doesn't contain z") - because colors don't always tell you the whole story. But yea it depends on who your audience is.